# RecyclerView throwing java.lang.IllegalStateException: The speicified child already has a parent

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, illegalstateexception

My RecyclerView is throwing the above error while inflating inside a fragment within a Coordinator layout.. Is there any connection with the parent layout? I have viewed all answers related to this error but none could solve my problem. Here is the code for the fragment + adapter

```
public static class EditJob extends Fragment {

    ServerRequests serverRequests;
    UserLocalStore userLocalStore;
    User receivedUser;
    EditText searchJob;
    ImageView searchBtn;
    RecyclerView editJobRecycler;
    MyRecyclerAdapter editJobAdapter;
    ArrayList<Job> arrayJob;
    TextView noJobSearch;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        serverRequests = new ServerRequests(context);
        userLocalStore = new UserLocalStore(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_job, container, false);
        receivedUser = userLocalStore.getAllDetails();
        arrayJob = new ArrayList<>();
        noJobSearch = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.noJobEdit);
        searchJob = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etEditJob);
        searchBtn = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.editJobImage);
        editJobRecycler = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.jobEditRecycler);
        editJobAdapter = new MyRecyclerAdapter(arrayJob);
        editJobRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        editJobRecycler.setAdapter(editJobAdapter);
        searchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                searchJob();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    public void searchJob() {
        arrayJob.clear();
        serverRequests.searchJobListings(searchJob.getText().toString(), new GetJobObjectsCallBack() {
            @Override
            public void done(Job[] returnedJobs) {
                if (returnedJobs == null || returnedJobs.length == 0) {
                    noJobSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    noJobSearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    for (int i = 0; i < returnedJobs.length; i++) {
                        arrayJob.add(i, returnedJobs[i]);
                    }
                    editJobAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerAdapter.VH> {

        ArrayList<Job> jobArray;

        public MyRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<Job> jl) {
            jobArray = jl;
        }

        @Override
        public VH onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            View v = li.inflate(R.layout.job_item_list, parent);
            return new VH(v);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(VH holder, int position) {
            Job current = jobArray.get(position);
            holder.jobID.setText(current.getID());
            holder.jobDescription.setText(current.getDescription());
            holder.jobDomain.setText(current.getDomain());
            holder.jobExperience.setText(current.getExperience());
            holder.jobRemarks.setText(current.getRemarks());
            holder.jobLocation.setText(current.getLocation());
            holder.jobPosition.setText(current.getID());
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return jobArray.size();
        }

        public class VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            TextView jobID, jobPosition, jobExperience, jobRemarks, jobLocation, jobDescription, jobDomain;
            EditText etjobID, etjobPosition, etjobExperience, etjobRemarks, etjobLocation, etjobDescription, etjobDomain;
            Button bEditJob;

            public VH(View v) {
                super(v);
                jobID = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.returnedJobID);
                jobExperience = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.returnedJobExperience);
                jobRemarks = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.returnedJobRemarks);
                jobLocation = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.returnedJobLocation);
                jobDescription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.returnedJobDescription);
                jobDomain = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.returnedJobDomain);
                jobPosition = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.returnedJobPosition);
                etjobID = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.etreturnedJobID);
                etjobPosition = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.etreturnedJobPosition);
                etjobExperience = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.etreturnedJobExperience);
                etjobRemarks = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.etreturnedJobRemarks);
                etjobLocation = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.etreturnedJobLocation);
                etjobDescription = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.etreturnedJobDescription);
                etjobDomain = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.etreturnedJobDomain);
                bEditJob = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.bEditJob);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

XML for the fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        style="@style/FloatingTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:elevation="6dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etEditJob"
            style="@style/FloatingTextView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editJobDivider"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:hint="Enter a search term"
            android:translationZ="0dp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/editJobDivider"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editJobImage"
            android:alpha="0.2"
            android:background="@color/Black" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/editJobImage"
            style="@style/FloatingTextView"
            android:layout_width="47dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:alpha="0.5"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search_black_48dp"
            android:translationZ="0dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/noJobEdit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No Jobs match your query"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/jobEditRecycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

XML for the activity:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adminCoordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/adminViewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <!-- <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer_admin" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout> -->
```

I've tried everything including parent.removeAllViews() but nothing seems to work. I have implemented other RecyclerViews as well with almost identical code but all of them work just fine. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try to change it as ... 
`View v = li.inflate(R.layout.job_item_list, parent,false);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change it as ...

```
View v = li.inflate(R.layout.job_item_list, parent,false);
```